# Consonant transposition: Why is "Wednesday" pronounced "Wensday"?

Tags: pronunciation, history, silent-letters

It appears like a couple of consonant sounds have been transposed.  How, why did that happen?

Comment: I don't see anything transposed: the [d] has been dropped, and so has the [e]: Wednesday -> We[d]n[e]sday -> Wensday.

Comment: Also, it would be better to have "sometimes" in your question, since pronunciation varies.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I seem to pronounce and conceptualize it as "Wendzday", so there is some transposition, at least in my idiolect. But I'm not sure if that has any linguistic significance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Wednesday derived from Odin (Odin's Day) the n was already the stressed/more prominent sound. Over time, the o sound shifted into a W taking along the stress with it. Since English lacks a stop and this DN is such a difficult letter pairing, I suspect the n simply won out over time. No transposition was needed.

Comment: More precisely, *Wednesday* and *Odin* are derived from a common root: *[Wednesday](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Wednesday&allowed_in_frame=0)* derives from Gmc. *Wodnesdæg* ("Woden's day"). *[Odin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Odin&allowed_in_frame=0)* derives from O.N. *Oðinn*, from  P.Gmc. **Wod-enaz-*. It's this **Wod-enaz-* where O.E. *Woden* and O.H.G. *Wuotan* come from.